# How to remove this ceiling lamp cover

Tags: light-fixture, lamp

I live in a dorm and my ceiling lamp died, i wanted to know how to remove this cover? 
it is attached flush to the ceiling, i tried rotating it both ways and also tried pulling it, but it wont come off.
I noticed that its feels a bit springy when I pull it, but I fear i will break it if i pull it too hard.
can anyone help me??

[image]

Comment: Doesn't your dorm have a maintenance team to take care of it?

Answer (score 1):

Pull harder, it probably has a couple of metal arms holding it in place. http://technical.sabhlokcity.com/2013/11/how-to-open-twist-off-the-cover-of-some-really-stupid-awkward-flush-mounted-ceiling-light-dome-fittings-fixture-to-replace-change-light-bulb/

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Can you highlight the relevant portion(s) from your link in your answer, in case the link goes dead?